# How to remove unknown white border of asp:image inside panel

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have white border of an asp:image control and i want to remove it but can't find where the problem is

here is my html and css:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="nav" ID="nav">
     <asp:Image runat="server" ID="Logo" CssClass="logo" />
     <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lb1" CssClass="navButtons">Home</asp:LinkButton>
     <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" CssClass="navButtons">Restorant</asp:LinkButton>
     <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton2" CssClass="navButtons">Rooms</asp:LinkButton>
     <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton3" CssClass="navButtons">Spa</asp:LinkButton>       
     <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton4" CssClass="navButtons">Contact</asp:LinkButton>
     <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton5" CssClass="navButtons">Contact</asp:LinkButton>
     <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton6" CssClass="navButtons">Contact</asp:LinkButton>
</asp:Panel>
```

the image with ID="Logo" is white bordered and i need to remove this border

CSS of image and Nav panel:

```
.logo {
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    background-image:url(Background/logo.jpg);
    float:left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%; 
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    position:relative;
    border:none;    
}

.nav {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:black;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    height:550px;
    width:250px;
    z-index:3;
    max-height:550px;
    max-width:250px;
}
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) that clearly demonstrates your issue

Comment: use developer console (f12) to identify what style setting creates the white border. Or override the existing border with transparent color in css